# Replace key values in a python csv Dictreader object

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to replace the "1" values in a spreadsheet with "0".  For workflow reasons I would like read the data in a as a csv Dictreader object.  However I am confused by this data type and get quite get the code to work.  Here is the input:

```
>>> print inreader
[{'PERSON1': '1', 'PERSON2': '1', 'GENE': 'TEST1', 'PERSON4': '1', 'PERSON3': '1'}, {'PERSON1': '1', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST2', 'PERSON4': '0', 'PERSON3': '0'}, {'PERSON1': '1', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST3', 'PERSON4': '0', 'PERSON3': '1'}, {'PERSON1': '0', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST4', 'PERSON4': '0', 'PERSON3': '0'}, {'PERSON1': '-', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST5', 'PERSON4': '-', 'PERSON3': '0'}, {'PERSON1': '2', 'PERSON2': '1', 'GENE': 'TEST9', 'PERSON4': '2', 'PERSON3': '1'}]
```

The following code will update just the values appropriately, but I can't figure out how to update the entire Dictreader object according to these rules.

```
>>>for line in inreader:
>>>    newline = [v.replace('1', '0') for k,v in line.items() ]
>>>    print newline

['0', '0', 'TEST0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', 'TEST2', '0', '0']
['0', '0', 'TEST3', '0', '0']
['0', '0', 'TEST4', '0', '0']
['-', '0', 'TEST5', '-', '0']
['2', '0', 'TEST9', '2', '0']
```

I would ideally like to create a new "inreader" object with with the values above replacing the original values.

Comment: What do you do with the output of the dictReader? Do you only want to replace the 1s and 0s in your script? Or, do you wish to create a new file with the 1s replaced with 0s?

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily need to make a new file, but I wanted to have the option just in case.  I use a lot of flat files with headers and the CSV module is great for that type of stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
inreader = [{'PERSON1': '1', 'PERSON2': '1', 'GENE': 'TEST1', 'PERSON4': '1', 'PERSON3': '1'}, {'PERSON1': '1', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST2', 'PERSON4': '0', 'PERSON3': '0'}, {'PERSON1': '1', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST3', 'PERSON4': '0', 'PERSON3': '1'}, {'PERSON1': '0', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST4', 'PERSON4': '0', 'PERSON3': '0'}, {'PERSON1': '-', 'PERSON2': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST5', 'PERSON4': '-', 'PERSON3': '0'}, {'PERSON1': '2', 'PERSON2': '1', 'GENE': 'TEST9', 'PERSON4': '2', 'PERSON3': '1'}]
result = []
for line in inreader:
    newline = dict([(k,v.replace('1', '0')) for k,v in line.items() ])
    result.append(newline)

print result
```

the result is

```
[{'PERSON2': '0', 'PERSON3': '0', 'PERSON1': '0', 'PERSON4': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST0'}, {'PERSON2': '0', 'PERSON3': '0', 'PERSON1': '0', 'PERSON4': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST2'}, {'PERSON2': '0', 'PERSON3': '0', 'PERSON1': '0', 'PERSON4': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST3'}, {'PERSON2': '0', 'PERSON3': '0', 'PERSON1': '0', 'PERSON4': '0', 'GENE': 'TEST4'}, {'PERSON2': '0', 'PERSON3': '0', 'PERSON1': '-', 'PERSON4': '-', 'GENE': 'TEST5'}, {'PERSON2': '0', 'PERSON3': '0', 'PERSON1': '2', 'PERSON4': '2', 'GENE': 'TEST9'}]
```

Comment: sometimes the little things are the hardest...thanks, that worked

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't simply replacing the values in `line` works ? :

```
>>>for line in inreader:
...    for k,v in line.items():
...        line[k] = v.replace('1', '0')
...    print line
```